# Duplicate file in Isolated Storage

Tags: windows-phone-7

I hope this is not a stupid question. So, I simply want to duplicate a file from the Isolated Storage to be used as a backup. However, speed is really important in this case and I wondered what's the fastest way to do that. Should I open the file from the IS, read it to a stream, then create a backup file and write to it, well from what I've seen so far this will take at least half a second which is a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no API for copy/duplicate so yes, your answer is the best way.

If you want to avoid the half a second delay then you'll need to do that via your application design - e.g. writing new data to a new file, or perhaps using smaller files.

If you're interested in the details of IsolatedStorage performance, then this blog has done a superb analysis:
http://appangles.com/blogs/mickn/wp7/?p=6

Comment: Thanks for the link, Stuart. It's a great article and from it I can tell that maybe most of the delay is because I was testing in debug on the emulator. Still, having a duplicate method would be nice.

Comment: You should also be able to open the read and write streams, and then use Stream.CopyTo; that would avoid having to read it all into memory first.